# Javascript can't detect collision axis between two Divs

Tags: javascript, html, math, collision

Am detecting if 2 divs overlap, and if they do, I am checking the distance between rectangle 1's right side and rectangle 2's left side, rectangle 1's top and rectangle 2's bottom, ect, ect.

```
    if (rect1.right > rect2.left &&
        rect1.left < rect2.right &&
        rect1.top < rect2.bottom &&
        rect1.bottom > rect2.top) {

        //collision detected.

        var dtop = Math.abs(rect1.top - rect2.bottom);
        var dbot = Math.abs(rect1.bottom - rect2.top);
        var dright =Math.abs(rect1.right - rect2.left);
        var dleft = Math.abs(rect1.left - rect2.right);
        var closestSide = Math.min(dtop,dbot,dright,dleft);

        if (closestSide == dleft || dright) {
            collisionAxis = "x";
        } 

        if (closestSide == dtop || dbot) {
            collisionAxis = "y";
        } 

        alert("collisionAxis: " + collisionAxis);

        return collisionAxis;

    }
```

For some reason, collisionAxis is always being set to "y", `even when closestSide == dleft || dright`, which should set collisionAxis to "x"...

Here is a JSFiddle example.  The variable `collisionAxis` in my `DetectCollision` function should be set to "x" when the white rectangle collides with the black rectangle, since `closestSide = dright`, yet somehow it is being set to "y".

Can anyone please tell me why?

Comment: EDIT:  Added JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be,

```
    if (closestSide == dleft || closestSide == dright) {
        collisionAxis = "x";
    } 

    if (closestSide == dtop || closestSide == dtopdbot) {
        collisionAxis = "y";
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I can see the difference between this code and mine, but wouldn't closestSide == dleft || dright be the same thing logically?

By the way I will mark this as the answer when SO lets me in 3 minutes.

Comment: Of course they are not. `(closestSide == dleft || dright)` is considered as `((closestSide == dleft) || (dright))`. Because of that it will return true for all the `dright > 0` values. Same with the `(closestSide == dtop || dbot)`.

Comment: Ah ok, it's very helpful.  In my mind I was thinking it would evaluate to true if closestSide was equal to dleft OR dright.  I can understand the mistake I made now.